# Duplicate id issue, cannot reuse an id

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the following script :

`http://www.andwecode.com/playground-demo/pop-up-login-signup-box-jquery/#`

I've modified the Gmail and Facebook boxes in it, and I would like them to present a login form when I click on them. I tried this with Gmail box :

`<a href="#1" class="social_box google" id="login_form" >
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>`

Basically, I added the ID : `(id="login_form")` and it worked fine !

The problem is that you can use the ID just once. and when you do that the login button became useless ..

any idea how to make all the boxes go for the login form ?

Comment: I completely fail to understand your actual problem.

Comment: Can you show some live example or screenshot or something?

Comment: enter the link : http://www.andwecode.com/playground-demo/pop-up-login-signup-box-jquery/ this is a script for login and register to test the script hit login , or you can download and test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the functionality works only for one scenario is that **'`ID's` have to be unique'**, if you have duplicate ID's it will recognize only the id for the first element and it will ignore the rest.

You can achieve your result in two ways

1) **have same class** for all the boxes fb box,google box etc.
Example: **box-form** class for all the boxes

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#1" class="social_box google box-form"  >
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
<a href="#1" class="social_box fb box-form"  >
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('.box-form').click(function() {
    //code

});
```

2) Apply different id for each box and combine the id's in jquery

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#1" class="social_box google" id="login-form" >
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
    <a href="#1" class="social_box fb"  id="fb-form">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#login-form, #fb-form').click(function() {
        //code

    });
```